# How can I detect when a Socket.IO emit() was sent but not received by any .on() handler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io, ecmascript-6

I've run into a common debugging problem where a socket.io .emit() is sent but there is no corresponding .on() to catch the emit, however this basically fails silently.

Is there a way on the server or client to detect when an emit was sent or an on was received but there was no handler for that event?

For my purposes I'm using TypeScript/ES6 with Socket.IO/Socket.IO-client v1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by having the socket.io listener hijack the onevent method of sockets as they connect and comparing the emit event name to the keys of the events the socket is listening for:

(Note: this is the server version, on the client you want to use _callbacks and remove the '$' at the beginning of each key)

```
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    var onevent = socket.onevent;
    var eventNames = Object.keys(socket._events);
    socket.onevent = function (packet) {
        onevent.call(this, packet);// original call

        var eventName = packet.data[0];

        if(eventNames.indexOf(eventName) == -1){
            console.error('No handler for emitted event: '+eventName);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: That's a fair point about the nomenclature, I could see how it would confuse people not familiar with socket.io's workings. I've updated the code sample to be more conventional.

While I certainly would prefer an API-based solution, until someone comes up with one, this will have to do.

Comment: My answer is server-side, but actually works on both. In your defense I was struggling to phrase the problem and I can see how my brevity could be mistaken for a lack of effort. I appreciate your effort though, you convinced me to double back and try to find a solution on my own.

Comment: The code works fine, I've been using it all afternoon. It runs on both the client and the server. Basically when either side receives an emit if it doesn't have a registered on listener for that emit event it logs to the console. What this accomplishes is when you make a typo or forgot to register an event either side emits to this catches the orphaned emit and logs it to the console. Again, this is for debugging, not for production.

Comment: I did, in the first sentence. In the future if you don't understand a question, I'd recommend asking for clarification.

Comment: I thought I understood that you were looking for a way from the server to know when the client had no event handler for the message you were sending or vice versa, I provided an answer based on that understanding.  You didn't provide ANY feedback on my answer (except perhaps a downvote - not sure who did that).  Then, when you provided your own answer that did something completely different, I asked you a bunch of questions to which you took several hours to finally clarify.  Sorry I tried to help.  Bye.

Comment: It's alright, in the end I was able to resolve the problem despite your misunderstandings. Cheers.